# C++ Terminal-Output not one after another

Tags: c++, logging, terminal, network-programming

I'm sorry if this question sounds a little childish, but I'm very new to C++ and console applications.

I recently wrote a HTTP1.1-Client to down/upload files. Everything works fine. The Problem is that there are quite a lot of logs to be output on the terminal and there is also the content of the remote host that should be print to the terminal. At the end of the application some of the output is not well formed - sometimes the order ist not right and sometimes the messages are just broken apart.

The application does not use multithreading and uses the libraries SPDLOG and FMT::FORMAT to output the data. The code is way to big to be put in here but if you'd anyway like to see it i can as well post it here.

I'd be thankful for every suggestion about what I might have done wrong and what the problem might be. Thanks!

Comment: There are 2 possibilities I can see: 1) Your program *does* use multithreading, or 2) you have logging to `cout` *inside* functions that you call as arguments to `cout << `, so the output is interleaved.

Comment: @BoBTFish Thanks for your answer! I've got a function called "Logger" that handles the output - is that what you mean?